# How to replace laravel-mix new notification with existing one

Tags: php, node.js, webpack, laravel-5.4, laravel-mix

While running **`npm run watch`** is it possible to discard previous notification before adding new notification.

When any **`js/vue`** or **`scss`** file changes it fills the notifications a lot.

I am not sure, but other applications do replace previous notification or discard previous notification before creating one.

[image: Laravel Mix notification]